# SQL Change Null date or 1-1-1900 00:00:00 to Current Date

Tags: sql, date, coalesce, nullif

I googled a couple of hours so far, and tried many different things, but somehow what works with others doesn't seem to work on my dataset.

*EDIT: DBMS: SQL Server. + Code below

Let's say this is the dataset:

```
ID,VALIDFROM,VALIDTO

1,1-1-2012,1-1-1900 00:00:00

2,1-1-2016,1-3-2017 00:00:00

3,1-1-2017,1-3,2018 00:00:00

4,1-1-2017,1-1-1900 00:00:00

5,1-1-2018,1-1-1900 00:00:00
```

I want to convert the `NULL`'s to Today's date, but whenever I try to do that with `NULLIF` or `COALESCE`, SQL returns `1-1-1900 00:00:00`.

```
SELECT
A.CONTRACTLINEID,
A.CONTRACTID AS 'Contract ID',
COALESCE(C.RENTALCOSTTYPEID, 'LEEG') AS 'Component ID',
A.NAME AS 'Component',
A.LINETYPE AS 'Componenttype ID',
B.ENUMITEMLABEL AS 'Componenttype',
A.RENTALOBJECTID AS 'Vastgoed Object ID',
A.VALIDFROM,
--A.VALIDTO, -- 1-1-1900 00:00:00
--COALESCE(A.VALIDTO,Sysdate()) AS VALIDTO, -- ERROR
--COALESCE(A.VALIDTO,GETDATE()) AS VALIDTO, -- 1-1-1900 00:00:00
--COALESCE(A.VALIDTO,CURRENT_DATE) AS VALIDTO, -- ERROR
--NULLIF(A.VALIDTO,GETDATE()) AS VALIDTO, -- 1-1-1900 00:00:00
--NULLIF(A.VALIDTO,CURRENT_DATE) AS VALIDTO, -- ERROR
A.COSTSETTLEMENTID,
A.PRICEPERIODID,
A.DATAAREAID,
C.PRICEPRICEID AS 'Prijs ID',
COALESCE(C.PRICE, '0') AS 'Prijs',
C.FROMDATE AS 'Prijs Vanaf Datum',
C.TODATE AS 'Prijs T/m Datum',
COALESCE(C.NAME, 'LEEG') AS 'Component-Prijs',
D.CONTRACTSTATUS AS 'Contract Status'
FROM MRPMCCONTRACTLINES A
LEFT JOIN MRENUMS B ON
B.ENUMITEMVALUE = A.LINETYPE
AND B.ENUMID = 40021
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  TOP 1 *
    FROM    MRPMCINVOICELINE C
    WHERE   C.CONTRACTLINEID = A.CONTRACTLINEID AND C.DATAAREAID = '1'
    ORDER BY
            C.TODATE DESC
    ) C
LEFT JOIN PMCCONTRACT D ON
D.CONTRACTID = A.CONTRACTID --Following doesn't do anything so far 
UPDATE MRPMCCONTRACTLINES
SET VALIDTO = '01/01/2050' 
WHERE VALIDTO IS NULL 
OR LTRIM(RTRIM(VALIDTO)) = ''
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: For questions like this, you should give more details like DB Vendor and version. Since you have used NULLIF, I suppose it is MSSQL DB, you may try select NULLIF(todate, getdate()) from table this would work for nulls. And hopefully may guide you for further.

Comment: `COALESCE` should work. Please show your code. And what is your DBMS? SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: Standard SQL: `COALESCE(TODATE, CURRENT_DATE)`

Comment: SQL Server, and code added to the post.

Answer (score 4):

`COALESCE()` replaces `NULL` with a value so that is what you want.  `NULLIF()` replaces a value with `NULL` and doesn't apply here.

My guess is you are doing `COALESCE(TODATE,'')` which will replace `NULL` with the default datetime of `1-1-1900 00:00:00`.

Make sure you are feeding it today's date properly `COALESCE(TODATE,GETDATE())`

The function to get today's date will vary based on your DBMS.  Always tag your question with your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc..) to get the best answers.

Comment: I tried many different things now, one of them is COALESCE(A.VALIDTO,GETDATE()) AS VALID.TO, and it still returns 1-1-1900 00:00:00. I think the problem is that I work with PowerBI, and the 'nulls' are already converted to 1-1-1900 00:00:00 instead of NULL. So maybe there is a way to change a date of 1-1-1900 00:00:00 to GETDATE() or a random date in the future like 1-1-2050 00:00:00.

Comment: @titatovenaar Ahh, that explains why you were trying `NULLIF()` too.  Try changing the date to `NULL` then coalescing it back to today's date:  `COALESCE(NULLIF(A.VALIDTO,'1-1-1900 00:00:00'),GETDATE())`

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed the solution for my problem. Next time I'll try to be a bit less confusing. Cheers, Igor

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be using `NULLIF`, its purpose is to compare values. If you want to substitute a value for a null in a select statement, you would use `isnull` (for SQL server) or `ifnull` (for MySQL)